# Handling obsession with things like washing machine

Tags: toddler, behavior

My three year son is obsessed with some things like washing machine, vaccum cleaner etc. He will not let others to operate these things. He gets mad when someone handles these without him. He will start crying won't stop untill we turn it off and let him restart himself. He is obsessed with giving food to the cat as well.

Is this a problem.? How do I handle this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like he wants to be involved in "practical life skills". My boy "helps" with the hoover (particularly if he made the mess) loading and unloading the washing machine and tumble drier, hanging up (poorly, I might add) things that can't tumble dry as well as having a toddler sized sweeping brush. He went through a phase of helping unload the dishwasher, but isn't so obsessed now.

I say, embrace it, but in doing so you have to accept that it will take longer to do these things and be a bit of a game. He needs to learn these skills for life anyway.

You could take a look at the montessori approach to chores/practical life skills for ideas on what to expect.